# Installing media codecs without Internet connection

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, multimedia, codecs

I have a dual boot system with **Windows 7** and **Ubuntu** installed. I want to install the multimedia codecs but I do not have an Internet connection in Ubuntu. I do have a connection in Windows, instead.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at [**How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/1002/179042)

Comment: If windows 7 is dual booted and you have internet on windows why don't you have the net when using the ubuntu partition

Answer (score 0):

You can download packages manually and install them in Ubuntu.

Look at [here](https://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs) and select what you need, then download them from [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/).

In Ubuntu, you can use **mount(8)** to mount the Windows partition.

Then run

```
dpkg -i /path/to/your/deb/debname.deb
```

to install these packages.

Notice that you may have to prepare everything necessary and install them in order because dpkg cannot download dependencies.

Comment: and what are the important codecs for mp3 and mp4 files?

Comment: From wiki: **Many codecs are already available in the official Debian archive. These include codecs for MP3, H264, and AAC encoding and decoding. These codecs are made available through libraries such as the libav/ffmpeg libraries.**